# What is the commentary on Leviticus 21:2-4 - why is wife not included on the list

Tags: death, kohen-priest, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

[Leviticus 21:1-4](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.21.1-4?lang=bi&aliyot=0)

> The LORD said to Moses: Speak to the priests, the sons of Aaron, and
>   say to them: None shall defile himself for any [dead] person among his
>   kin, except for the relatives that are closest to him: his mother, his
>   father, his son, his daughter, and his brother; also for a virgin
>   sister, close to him because she has not married, for her he may
>   defile himself. But he shall not defile himself as a kinsman by
>   marriage, and so profane himself.

I think I understand why a priest would want to stay away from a dead body.  The body represents contagion.  It's also spoiling in the heat.

But why is wife excluded from the list?  A priest may be exalted (verse 10), but a priest is still a man and has emotions.  Surely he will grieve at the death of his wife - it is a major life event.  Is G-d so insensitive that he would deny the priest the opportunity to grieve at his wife's death?

Comment: The wife can be buried by her own (non-priestly) blood-relatives (most likely what kin means here, judging by context), but the priest's own blood-relatives cannot be buried by (random) strangers.

Answer (score 4):

A dead body, once the soul has left it, represents a source of impurity and a Kohen (priest) is prohibited from coming in contact with such a source of impurity.

**The Kohen's wife is not excluded from the list.** Rashi (on [21:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.21.2?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Leviticus.21.2.1&lang2=bi)) explains that "the relative that are closest to him" includes his wife. See also the gemara in [Yevamot 22b](https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.22b.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that it only includes his wife if she was a permitted marriage. Finally the Rambam in [Hilchot Aveilut 2:7](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1181883/jewish/Avel-Chapter-2.htm) explicitly mentions a Kohen is forced to contact ritual impurity to tend to his deceased wife.

Note in any case that grieving and touching the body are two separate things. Even when a Kohen is forbidden to touch a body, he still grieves and goes through the other mourning rituals.

Comment: +1. Sourcing your last sentence would improve your post IMO.

Comment: @msh210 I hear you. Interestingly the laws of mourning for non-Kohanim are learned from the Kohen: just as the Kohen mourns for the seven relatives in the OP's question, so do non-Kohanim mourn (see [Moed Katan 20b](https://www.sefaria.org/Moed_Katan.20b.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and [SA YD 374.4](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.374.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))